# Create directive with data transform

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-directive

I would like to create a LoaderDirective, which gets and observable, loads the data shows a spinner meanwhile, and when it is loaded it changes the spinner to the original data, while exposing the loaded data with the 'as' keyword.

I'd like to use it like this: `<div *load="items$ as items">`

This is what I have so far:

```
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[load]',
})
export class LoadDirective<T> {
  private data: T;

  @Input()
  set load(observable: Observable<T>) {
    observable.subscribe({
      next: value => this.loaded(value),
      error: error => this.showError(error)
    });
  }

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    this.viewContainer.createComponent(this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SpinnerComponent));
  }

  private loaded(value: T) {
    this.data = value;
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {load: this.data});
  }

  private showError(e: string) {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    const errorComponent = this.viewContainer.createComponent(this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ErrorComponent));
    errorComponent.instance.error = e;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the input data is an observable, so it expects the output to be Observable. Is there a similar way to change this than for example `TransformPipe` at pipes? How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I could do this using the async pip, but I find that redundant if I can do it inside the directive

Comment: I could create a workaround by renaming `load()` to `loadFor()` and then calling it like this: `<div *load="let items for items$">`. Not what I was looking for tho, so I will keep the question open.

Comment: I'm just curious: Why would you want to create a directive and not a component?

Comment: What I want to do is use the loaded observable (or the observed items) without subscribing in the component by hand and write all that boilerplate.

I think it is much nicer if I just use the async pipe and ngIf: `<div *ngIf="obs$ | async as loaded; else spinner"> <!-- do things with loaded --> </div> <ng-template #spinner>`. But this is redundant if I can write my own directive to do all this skipping the async pipe implementing my own: `<div *load="items$ as items">`. This lets me use the `items` anywhere inside the div which is what I want

Comment: No boilerplate for subscribing to observables and storing the result, no extra components, very nice and clean code, subscribed only once and result lives in the scope.

Comment: @godzsa What are the strict requirements for what you're after? Is it `*load="items$ as items"` or nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried, let me know if this works.

Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csogfu

Just a small modification to your code

**Changed from**

```
this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {load: this.data});
```

**to**

```
const viewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
viewRef.context.data = this.data;
```

**Template changed to**

```
<div *appLoader="data$; data as result">
    {{result | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: The first change is redundant - the updated template works either way. I was looking at solving with something like `data$; data as result`, but am not sure whether this meets the requirements of the question.